# Express/Nodemailer - send info to browser after sending email

Tags: javascript, express, axios, nodemailer

I'm vary new to express and I think I'm struggling with something what is not that hard...

I have a function sendEmail

```
exports.sendEmail = async (req, res) => {
  const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.MAIL_HOST,
    port: process.env.MAIL_PORT,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.MAIL_USER,
      pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD,
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  });

  await transport.sendMail(
    { body },
    (err, info) => {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(info);
// here is a problem
          if (err) {
           res.status(200).json({ msg: 'error' });
           throw err;
           } else {
             res.status(200).json({ msg: 'mesage  
             has been sent' });
           }
          );
```

This function works fine - email is send. But what I want to achieve is send info to browser with info 'is sent' or 'error'.

In frontend I have this code:

```
await axios.all([
      axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_DOMAIN}/api/send-email`, {
        data,
      }),
     
      axios
        .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_DOMAIN}/api/send-email`)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
        }),
    ]);
```

axios.post works fine, but axios.get is not. The response I get doesn't contain data I want.

Could anyone explain me how to send data I need to after email is sent?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use try catch block to send data to your client like this. When you send a post request either you will recive the information or the error.

try{
  const info = await transport.sendMail({ body }); 
  res.send(info);
}catch(error){
  res.status(500).send(error.message)
}

Comment: @MithatErcan thanks for your answer. I've tried that but still nothing. Maybe I'm doing sth wrong in axios call? I was searching the internet and found sth about res.locals and middlewares but in this approach I receive undefind :/

Answer (score 0):

What about using it promise-based

```
transport.sendMail(config)
.then(info => res.send(info))
.catch(e => res.send(e))
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried but didin't work out